# VBA Change OLAP Pivot Table Filter Based on Cell Reference

Tags: excel, vba, exception

I'm relatively new to VBA so looking for some help here. I'm currently trying to setup a macro that automatically changes a filter within an OLAP Pivot Table whenever I change a specific cell. I currently have the following code:

```
Sub Update_Dates()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IssuerListTest").PivotFields( _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].[Position Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].&[2019-06-30T00:00:00]", _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].&[2019-09-30T00:00:00]")
End Sub
```

However I want the "2019-06-30" and "2019-09-30" to be set dynamically from a different sheet named "Configuration Sheet" within the same workbook in cells B1 and B2 respectively. The other problem I'm currently facing is I have to manually run the macro. Is there a way that someone can explain on how the macro can automatically run once the dates are changed within either of those cells?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your sub with this:

```
Sub Update_Dates()
    Dim B1  As String
    Dim B2  As String

    B1 = Format(Sheets("Configuration Sheet").Range("B1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    B2 = Format(Sheets("Configuration Sheet").Range("B2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IssuerListTest").PivotFields( _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].[Position Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].&[" & B1 & "T00:00:00]", _
        "[Position Date].[Position Date].&[" & B2 & "T00:00:00]")
End Sub
```

If you want to run this sub every time you change the B1 or B2 cells, you need to add in your "Configuration Sheet" sheet module the event sub like e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Update_Dates
    End If
End Sub
```

but.. in this case you should replace Activesheet with Sheets(yoursheetwithpivottablename) in Update_Dates() sub.